# Custom build vs dockware/dev:latest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to build a custom dockerfile for shopware6:latest :

```
FROM ghcr.io/friendsofshopware/shopware-cli AS shopware-cli
FROM node:18 AS node
FROM php:8.2-fpm

ARG UNAME=www-data
ARG UGROUP=www-data
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
RUN usermod  --uid $UID $UNAME
RUN groupmod --gid $GID $UGROUP

COPY --from=shopware-cli /usr/local/bin/shopware-cli /usr/local/bin/shopware-cli

COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm
RUN chown -R $UID:$GID "/var/www/"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
    jq \
    vim \
    cron \
    git \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    libzip-dev \
    redis-server \
    openssh-client \
    mariadb-client \
    apt-transport-https \
    git \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libyaml-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install xsl
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install sodium
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN pecl install -o -f apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN pecl install -o -f yaml && docker-php-ext-enable yaml
RUN pecl install -o -f redis &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN curl -sOL https://getcomposer.org/download/2.0.13/composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer && composer self-update
```

And when I try to execute `bin/watch-storefront.sh` it takes almost 1 minute to build all bundles and run the watcher

In another case, when I'm using dockware/dev:latest the build is running for about 3 seconds.

What could be the cause?

I thought the volumes could be the cause, so I removed `volume` from `Dockerfile` and replaced it with manually copying the files, but it did not help me.

I am using `Apple M2 Pro`

The script `bin/watch-storefront.sh` under the hood is doing:
`webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js`